# outlook VBAを使用した最新メールの添付ファイルを特定のフォルダへ取り込む方法

Tags: vba

下記のページを参考に、「あさ」というフォルダ内の最新受信1件の添付ファイルを対象`(C:\保存フォルダ)` へ保存できるようにしようとしています。

https://tonari-it.com/outlook-vba-mail-attachment-saveasfile/
https://tonari-it.com/outlook-vba-subfolder-mail-attachmentfile/

素人目で `Set objItem =` がフォルダ内の最新を選択できれば動くように感じますが、このままだと

```
For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
```

でエラーが出てしまいます。
修正方法を教えていただきたいです。

ここからコード

```
Sub SaveAttachmentFile()
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objIns As Inspector
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim objAttachment As Object

Set objIns = Application.ActiveInspector
Set myNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objItem = myInbox.Folders.Item("あさ")

strPath = "C:\保存フォルダ\"

With objItem

    For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
        strFile = strPath & objAttachment
        objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFile
    Next objAttachment
End With

End Sub
```

コメントいただき、変更後

```
Sub SaveAttachmentFile()
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objIns As Inspector
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim objAttachment As Object

Set objIns = Application.ActiveInspector
Set myNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objItem = myInbox.Folders.Item("あさ")
strPath = "C:\保存フォルダ\"

With objItem
If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "メールに添付ファイルがありません。"
        End If

        strFile = strPath & .Attachments.Item(1)
    For Each objAttachment In .Attachments
        strFile = strPath & objAttachment
        objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFile
    Next objAttachment
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 単に「エラーになる」とだけ書くより、具体的にどんなエラーになるのかメッセージ等も含めて書いておくと回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 助言有難うございます。　質問の仕方も考えなければ行けませんね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「添付ファイルが無かった場合」が考慮されていないのが原因ではないでしょうか？

参考にされたサイトに掲載されているコードでは以下のようにチェックを行っています。

```
Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem   '今開いているメールオブジェクトを取得

    With objItem

        '添付ファイルの数が0だったら処理終了
        If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox　"メールに添付ファイルがありません。"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        strFile = strPath & .Attachments.Item(1)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確認しましたが、まだエラーになります。　というより　Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 部分を　Set objItem = myInbox.Folders.Item("あさ")　に変えているのですが、それが問題なのでしょうか。　なかった場合は考慮する必要はある為、追加させていただきました。　ありがとうございます。